# Add page in Word Options menu

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I'm developing and add-in for Word. 
I would like to create a configuration screen that allows the user to configure the add-in.
What is the right way to do that?

Is it possible to add configuration screen to the "Word Options" menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, extending the built-in *Options* dialog is not supported by Microsoft Word (not even using hacks such as Window subclassing)

You will have to provide a separate UI for accessing your add-in options. You can do so e.g. using a modal dialog accessible via a *Ribbon* button or using a page in the backstage view (available for Office 2010 or later only).